# PHP 5.4.16 on Ubuntu 16

Tags: server, apache2, mysql, php

I'm trying to install PHP 5.4.15 on Ubuntu 16. Need this version of PHP because of old site. Found installation of PHP 5.4.15, installed.

```
$ php -v
PHP 5.4.15 (cli) (built: Mar  5 2018 13:49:42)
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
```

but can`t find modules that integrates with apache and mysql, could you please guide to where to search ?

Comment: Please try if this ppa still works: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39824219/install-php-5-3-or-5-4-on-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-and-apache

Comment: ppa:ondrej/php5-oldstable,  doesn`t work anymore